# PyDev running pytest unit test with module-shared fixture fails

Tags: python, unit-testing, pydev, pytest

I have a problem running pytest unit tests with pyDev. I try to run a unit test with a module shared fixture and a finalizer which should be excecuted after the last test. 
But when running the unit test in pyDev it does not use the same instance but instead creates two different instances. The example is running fine in the console or when started from a script within pydev.

I'm using platform Python 2.7.3, pytest-2.3.4, pyDev 2.7.3.2013031601, Eclipse 4.2 on Win7.

I tried the example from http://pytest.org/latest/fixture.html

The output from pydev is:

```
============================= test session starts ==============================
platform win32 -- Python 2.7.3 -- pytest-2.3.4
__________________________________ test_ehlo ___________________________________
smtp = <smtplib.SMTP instance at 0x027F9080>
__________________________________ test_noop ___________________________________
smtp = <smtplib.SMTP instance at 0x027FF3C8>
```

The console output is:

```
============================= test session starts ==============================
platform win32 -- Python 2.7.3 -- pytest-2.3.4
__________________________________ test_ehlo ___________________________________
smtp = <smtplib.SMTP instance at 0x01E51288>
__________________________________ test_noop ___________________________________
smtp = <smtplib.SMTP instance at 0x01E51288>
```

Which is the expected behaviour. What am I doing wrong??

the used code is conftest.py:

```
import pytest
import smtplib

@pytest.fixture(scope="module")
def smtp():
return smtplib.SMTP("merlinux.eu")
```

The test code in test_smtplib.py:

```
# content of test_module.py
def test_ehlo(smtp):
    response = smtp.ehlo()
    assert response[0] == 250
    assert "merlinux" in response[1]
    assert 0  # for demo purposes

def test_noop(smtp):
    response = smtp.noop()
    assert response[0] == 250
    assert 0  # for demo purposes
```

Running the test from script with:

```
import pytest,os
os.chdir("[path_to_tests]/tests") #your file location
pytest.main(['-s', 'test_smtplib.py'])
```

Any suggestions and thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Did you configure your PyDev IDE to use the **py.test** test runner (*Window -> Preferences -> PyDev -> PyUnit -> Test Runner*)?

Comment: Yes, PyDev Test Runner is selected.

Comment: No, not the *PyDev Test Runner*, you should also have the ability to choose the ***Py.test** Test Runner* -> look: http://up.picr.de/14054750vh.jpg

Comment: Sorry, of course I meant **Py.test** Test Runner. I can use py.Test with my other tests. But it is not working with the module-shared fixture. Thanks for your help. I really appreciate it.

Comment: If you are creating the runner file (containing `pytest.main()`) then you should be starting it with `python /path/to/your/runner.py`.  Try not using the PyUnit then.

Comment: Don't know how this can happen.  Could you add another test function using the module-scoped smtp fixture?   Do you then see three different smtp instances?

Comment: Same behaviour here. PyDev wont take `scope` in to account. Works fine from the command line, though.
Looks like it is caused by PyDev's overrides used to display fancy PyUnit view.

Comment: +1 ... same behavior with my PyDev setup

Comment: @MBaumann Maybe this is totally off base, but maybe PyDev is using multiprocessing, creates separate objects, and pulls them back together with unexpected results? Do the modules have `if __name__ ...` protection for multiprocessing on them? Sorry I don't use PyDev or I would just try it myself.

Comment: @kobejohn That was my first guess as well--I wonder if PyDev is running the tests on multiple processes by default.

Comment: Did you get a chance to the try the long-shot answer I posted? (Iguananaut - sorry - I thought you were the OP when I made the comment.)

Answer (score 1):

I don't have eclipse but I've been looking through the source code for Pydev and pytest. pytest doesn't use multiprocessing by default but it will if you have xdist installed. Perhaps you have it? Or perhaps Eclipse has installed it?

If you still have the system available, can you try setting the option below in your pytest parameters? It simply tells pytest to use one process when using xdist [as documented here](http://pytest.org/latest/xdist.html#speed-up-test-runs-by-sending-tests-to-multiple-cpus).

`-n=1` or perhaps it will prefer `-n 1`

If that doesn't work, then this also shouldn't work but could you try it? Use the option below in the ***pytest*** options as before (not in the pydev test runner options) to enable module-level testing. It's a pydev test runner option so I guess it will cause an error, but maybe some other code that keys off the option will make use of it.

`--split_jobs=module` or again perhaps `--split_jobs module`

Answer (score 1):

Seems like this is a long-standing bug on the pydev side.  I just fixed it and submitted a pull request to Pydev, see https://github.com/fabioz/Pydev/pull/120 .  In the meanwhile, you could probably take out the little change and apply to your installed version of pydev, enabling proper pydev/pytest runs with scoping.

Comment: Just applied the fix. It'll be available in the nightly build shortly (and the next release with the fix will be PyDev 3.5.0)

Comment: It's 2018 already and I got here, because I've just got this error in the pydev. (don't have xdist installed).